# User login keeps redirecting back to login Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I'm working with sessions for a login function. However every time I attempt log in it just keeps redirecting to the login screen. Below is the code. There is a function set to say that the login is invalid, that is not sending out an error so I'm not sure that it is a login issue.

**ATIS Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Atis extends CI_Controller 
{
        public $status; 
        public $roles;
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('User_model', 'user_model', TRUE);
    $this->status = $this->config->item('status'); 
    $this->roles = $this->config->item('roles');    
    $this->is_logged_in();
    }

function index(){   
    $this->load->view("atis/inc/header");
    $this->load->view("atis/dashboard");
    $this->load->view("atis/inc/footer");
    }
function is_logged_in()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if(!isset($is_logged_in) || is_logged_in !==true)
    {
        redirect('main/login');
    }
}
```

**Main Controller**

```
 public function login()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');    
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required'); 

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('inc/site_header');
                $this->load->view("site_nav"); 
                $this->load->view('login');
                $this->load->view('inc/site_footer');
            }else{

                $post = $this->input->post();  
                $clean = $this->security->xss_clean($post);

                $userInfo = $this->user_model->checkLogin($clean);

                if(!$userInfo){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'The login was unsucessful');
                    redirect(site_url().'main/login');
                }                
                foreach($userInfo as $key=>$val){
                    $this->session->set_userdata($key, $val);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in');
                }
                redirect(site_url().'atis/');
            }

        }
```

**Check login method**

```
public function checkLogin($post)
    {
        $this->load->library('password');       
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('email', $post['email']);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $userInfo = $query->row();

        if(!$this->password->validate_password($post['password'], $userInfo->password)){
            error_log('Unsuccessful login attempt('.$post['email'].')');
            return false; 
        }

        $this->updateLoginTime($userInfo->id);

        unset($userInfo->password);
        return $userInfo; 
    }
```

**Yard Function from ATIS Controller**

```
public function yard()

    {
        $this->load->model('atisyard_model');
        $this->data['yards'] = $this->atisyard_model->getyardname();
        $this->data['trackdatabase'] = $this->atisyard_model->gettrains();
        $this->load->view("atis/inc/header");
        $this->load->view('atis/yard_view', $this->data);
        $this->load->view("atis/inc/footer");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `$` in `if(!isset($is_logged_in) || is_logged_in !==true)`

Or if still does not work, try changing

```
if(!isset($is_logged_in) || is_logged_in !==true)
```

to

```
if(!$is_logged_in)
```

Comment: Now when I try to go to the secure area it bypasses the login form entirely and just goes directly to the secure area.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in');
```

is not correct. You should pass something like

```
$this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in', TRUE);
```

or

```
$this->session->set_userdata($arr);
```

to have it valid. [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data).

Edit:

In controller, change this

```
if(!$userInfo)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'The login was unsucessful');
    redirect(site_url().'main/login');
}
foreach($userInfo as $key=>$val)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata($key, $val);
    $this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in');
}
redirect(site_url().'atis/');
```

to this

```
if(!$userInfo)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'The login was unsucessful');
    redirect(site_url().'main/login');
}
else
{
    foreach($userInfo as $key=>$val)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata($key, $val);
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in', TRUE);
    redirect(site_url().'atis/');
}
```

Edit: 20160130002859

In `is_logged_in()` method you are checking `if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in !==true)` which is paradoxal. In any case right side of condition will be `FALSE`. This is because of fact `$is_logged_in` nevere can be boolean `TRUE` by type if not casted explicitly. It is object. So you should check in other ways:

```
$is_logged_in != TRUE // this way you don't check for type
```

or

```
is_object($is_logged_in)
```

Comment: This did not work either, it still goes straight to the secure area without asking me to log in

Comment: Post this method `$this->user_model->checkLogin($clean);`. Also clean session table and put `exit();` after `redirect(site_url().'main/login');` in `main/login`.

Comment: I posted the method above in the body of the question.

Comment: Still not working, still goes directly to the secure page

Comment: Put `var_dump($clean); exit;` just before calling model to see whar is there.

Comment: It puts out the email address and password that is used to log in.

Comment: Just checking if it is in form of associative array. Seems something is wrong with Password library to me. Not sure tho. Change your model db code for this one: `$query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $post['email']));`. This is more like blind try.

Comment: I'm still getting the same results as before.

Comment: That seemed to work, now however when I try to access a function so for example www.mysite.com/atis/[function] it asks me to log in again. Only one of the functions does not require me to log in again.

Comment: Since method of check is in constructor, it should work for all methods. Close browser, delete all session data, open browser and clear cache from it (Ctrl+F5).

Comment: I can't help more without appropriate code. "Only one of the functions does not require me to log in again" does not tell me a thing to let me offer eventual solution.

Comment: I added the function in question to the body of the question. This function is accessed from a link on the view that is in the atis index. The link looks like www.mysite.com/atis/yard/[uri segment 3 = yard id].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102052/discussion-between-tpojka-and-david).

Comment: I found that if i removed the redirect('main/login'); from the $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'); 
if(!$is_logged_in) 
{ 
redirect('main/login'); 

However when I did that it let me go to the yard pages with out logging in. I don't know if I'm on to something with this or not.